# F Select showing the current value in the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following as my f select

How do i modify to show what is in the database?

```
 <%= f.select :phase_names, options_for_select([["Select One", "", @phase_names_string_value], "RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]), :class => 'inputboxes' %>
```

Phase Names is from a second table in the database.
however each project can only sit in one phase at a time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
```

The container is display\value combination so you need `[[value,name],[value,name]]` or if its the same `[name]`

Like `["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]`

Now that you have the container you need something to match the selected value

```
@current_value = MyModel.find(1).vari  # Assume MyModel table with id has col vari=Completed
```

Then, you can do

```
select_tag "select_name", options_for_select(["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"].insert(0, "Select One"), @current_value)
```

Another way to do it is to have a collection of an object that holds the options with lets say `:name` (displayed) and `:value` (used as value) where selected has `:phase_names = :value`

```
f.collection_select :phase_names, [:name => "rStage", :value => "Pre Contract"] , :value, :name, {:include_blank => 'Select one'}
```

Which works just as activerecord classes

Comment: Thanks this is what i tried:

     <%= f.select :phase_names, options_for_select([[@phase_names =:name],"RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]), :class => 'inputboxes' %>

However it is displaying "name" now on the select

Comment: phase_names is from a second database table sorry forgot to mention earlier, so each project is like "tagged" with a phase 
Edited the Question to correct

Comment: This option not storing in the database

 <%= collection_select(:phase_names, :phase_id, Phase.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true }) %>

Comment: Debug and check what the select is returning as a value in the params[]